# How to plot columns from reactive element in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

This is my first app that I am making using Shiny, and I am having some trouble with my reactive plot. My end goal is to be able to use the drop down menu to select client A-D and then plot the datapoints from the columns (Date, ModResult) in a scatterplot when the Update button is pressed. Right now it returns "Error in axis: no locations are finite." The labData data frame has 7 columns: "Client.Name" is column 1, "Date" is column 4, and "ModResult" is column 7. Please let me know if there is any more information that could help in debugging this error!

Thank you!

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel("Dilution History"),
  selectInput(inputId="client", label="Select Client Name", 
choices=levels(labData$Client.Name)), actionButton("update", "Update"), 
hr(),
  plotOutput("line")
)


server <- function(input, output, session){
#selected client into data frame
selDF <- reactive({data.frame(labData[labData[,1] =="input$client",])
  })   
  output$line <- renderPlot({
    plot(selDF()$Date, selDF()$ModResult, ylab="Result", main="Results 
For Client X Between Xdate and Ydate")
  })
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: By best guess is `labData[,1] =="input$client" needs to be labData[,1] ==input$client`. If this is not the problem please attached some sample data so that we can debug it.

Comment: Welcome to SO Camellia, Your question can be best answered with a minimum reproducible example that should include a dummy data. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

After few modifications

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel("Dilution History"),
                selectInput(inputId = "client", label = "Select Client Name", 
                            choices = levels(labData$Clientname)), submitButton("update"), 
                hr(),
                plotOutput("line")
)


server <- function(input, output, session){

selDF <- reactive({data.frame(labData[labData$Clientname == input$client,])
  })
  output$line <- renderPlot({
    plot(selDF()$date, selDF()$result, ylab = "Result", main = "Results For Client X Between Xdate and Ydate")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```